# How to change the file naming scheme for screen shot

Tags: command-line, gnome, screenshot, special-characters, filename

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and when I take the screen shot, the default file name is given like `Screenshot from 2016-02-29 11:08:10.png`. I do not want the file name to have a space () and a colon (`:`). How can I change the file naming scheme?

Comment: @norio,  would you be alright if the only mode where it doesn't work is interactive ? DK Bose's answer pretty much is the best solution. For some odd reason developers decided to disable filename option in the interactive mode , and we don't have much control over that, i suppose

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-f` option as described in [`man gnome-screenshot`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/gnome-screenshot.1):

```
-f, --file=FILENAME
              Save screenshot directly to this file.
```

So, try

```
gnome-screenshot -f Screenshot_from_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S").png
```

On my system, the image is saved to my home folder. If you want it to be saved elsewhere, you need to specify the path like this, for example:

```
gnome-screenshot -f ~/Pictures/Screenshot_from_$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S").png
```

Read http://www.foragoodstrftime.com or [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/date.1) for more on formatting dates.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the naming for file in `gnome-screenshot`  is hardcoded into the source, specifically the `screenshot-filename-builder.c` part of the source code. If you specifically want to use `gnome-screenshot`, your best bet is to alter the source code.

There also are no external settings for that.

```
grep '<key.*\=' /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.gnome-screenshot.gschema.xml                              
    <key type="b" name="take-window-shot">
    <key type="i" name="delay">
    <key type="s" name="auto-save-directory">
    <key type="s" name="last-save-directory">
    <key type="b" name="include-border">
    <key type="b" name="include-pointer">
    <key type="b" name="include-icc-profile">
    <key type="s" name="border-effect">
    <key name="default-file-type" enum="org.gnome.gnome-screenshot.file-types">
```

You could always use the `--file=` flag in conjunction with `date` program.  DK Bose actually posted this solution earlier, which baffles me why he deleted it.  One could connect `gnome-screenshot --file="$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S).png"` to a shortcut. That's the closest to what OP wants.  And you could always seek alternatives,too, for instance `shutter` is a popular screenshot software on Linux, but I've never used it myself, so cannot endorse

Comment: I undeleted my answer! I confused `--interactive` with `--area` in my mind. Thanks for pointing out that my answer is satisfactory.

Comment: @DKBose yup, no problem. Keep up the good work ! I've already had your answer upvoted